# cocos2d scene dealloc

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a Cocos2d scene (CCLayer) with a CCMenu. I implement the dealloc as

```
- (void) dealloc {
    [menu release];
    menu = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

when i use shared director to replace the scene with an other, it load the second scene and then program crash in dealloc, especially in

```
[super dealloc]; //Thread1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
```

The call to replace the scene is

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:
     [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[SomeOtherScene scene]]];
```

Why is this happens? Should i call [super dealloc] or not?

Comment: You should really be using ARC for new projects. Here's how to enable it for cocos2d: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set menu to nil THEN release it, that may be your issue. And to answer your second question yes you definitely should call [super dealloc] or it could cause more issues.

Comment: Sorry Im looking at http://www.raywenderlich.com/2657/memory-management-in-objective-c-tutorial and he does release THEN nil so I believe your correct. Sorry Ive been using ARC for all of my projects lately. But do call [super dealloc];

Comment: Setting to nil and THEN releasing doesn't release anything, why? Because you are sending a release message to nil, which does nothing. What's probably the problem is that @pbaris never retained or copied the menu, so he's releasing an object without having ownership of it.

Comment: This answer may cause a leak, if you are losing your only reference to an alloc'd object you will never be able to properly release it.

Comment: what is the proper way to do it? my interface is Scene : CCLayer { CCMenu *menu; }

Comment: Depends on how you created the CCMenu, cocos2d was designed to kept memory management to a minimum and generally everything is autoreleased. However if you actually alloc'd it you would have to release it, but you could do that after you added it as a child.

Answer (score 2):

If you created `menu` with `[CCMenu menuWithItems:...]`, you don't need to release it in `dealloc`, because it has not been retained.